# Creating array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Updated Question. How can i add additional column in array. I want to add a column distance which is a result from the formula that i have created

Here's my code

```
    $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select('*')
                 ->from('#__listing');
     $db->setQuery($query);
      $db->query();

     $rows = $db->loadRowList();


$arr_data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $theta = $longitudeFrom - $row->longitude;
    $dist =   sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) 
            * sin(deg2rad($row>latitude)) 
            + cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) 
            * cos(deg2rad($row->latitude)) 
            * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $distance = $miles * 1.609344;
    $key = $row[0];
    $arr_data[$key] = array('id' => $row[0], 'name' => $row[1]);
}
```

This is what i have tried

```
$arr_data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $theta = $longitudeFrom - $row->longitude;
    $dist =   sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) 
            * sin(deg2rad($row>latitude)) 
            + cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) 
            * cos(deg2rad($row->latitude)) 
            * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $distance = $miles * 1.609344;

    $key = $row[0];
    $arr_data[$key] = array(
                        'id' => $row[0],
                        'name' => $row[1],
                        'distance' => $distance);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct understanding that you want to get new array which contains aggregated record for each record from $rows? If yes, you can do something like this:

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('*')
            ->from('#__listing');
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();

$rows = $db->loadAssocList();


$arr_data = [];
foreach ($rows as $rowIndex=>$rowData) {
    $theta = $longitudeFrom - $rowData['longitude'];
    $dist =   sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) 
            * sin(deg2rad($rowData['latitude'])) 
            + cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) 
            * cos(deg2rad($rowData['latitude'])) 
            * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $distance = $miles * 1.609344;

    $arr_data[$rowIndex] = [
        'id' => $rowData['id'],
        'name' => $rowData['name'],
        'distance' => $distance
    ];
}
```

**PS:** I'm using a shorthand array notation `[]`, but it is equal to `array()`

**PPS:** there is also an issue in the original code with treating `$row` variable as an object `$row->longitude` and than as an array `$row[1]`. Which one is correct depends on how you get `$rows`, but should not mix it anyway.

**PPPS:** as per comment bellow i've update my answer using loadAssocList to get associative array and changed

```
'id' => $rowData[0],
'name' => $rowData[1],
```

to

```
'id' => $rowData['id'],
'name' => $rowData['name'],
```

Assuming that your 'id' and 'name' fields are named respectively in DB.

Comment: and if i change the $miles to $rowData->id.. is that possible?

Comment: how will i get the row ID for instance? like this?
`$distance = $rowData->id * 1.609344;` ?

Comment: @JEROLDCOQUILLA it depends on what is inside of `$rows`. If it is an array of objects, than `$rowData->id`, alternatively, if each item in $rows is an array, than `$rowData['id']`

Comment: @JEROLDCOQUILLA please show how you getting initial data (`$rows`)

Comment: i select all from the database then use $arr_data = loadrowlist.. inside database there is id column,.  thats why i am wondering if i can do like this $RowData->id..

Comment: @JEROLDCOQUILLA could you please update your question and put a core related to defining `$rows`. `loadrowlist` doesn't seem to be any of standard php functions, so it is really hard to tell what are we dealing with - array of arrays or of objects.

Comment: @JEROLDCOQUILLA ok, i've made some googling for you and it seems you are using Joomla. If this if correct, than loadRowList returns an array of arrays, but indexed not by a field name, but by field index.
To make my code work you need to replace `loadRowList`, with `loadAssocList` which will return arrays indexed by field name. I'll update my answer to make it work. Here's Joomla doc on this matter https://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase#loadAssocList.28.29

Comment: oh thank you so much. i will wait for the answer. sorry im new to programming and this will so much appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200092/discussion-between-denis-o-and-jerold-coquilla).

Comment: Quick question. how do i sort it by distance ASC?